# Getting the size of parent folders when using find to search for criteria?

Tags: find, disk-usage, xargs, cut, uniq

I am hunting for a certain regular expression within the filenames and am seeking to return the parent folders with their sizes in a unique fashion.

For example, here is the command that I expected to work:

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*[fF][oO][oO].*' -maxdepth 2 | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev | egrep -v '\.$' | uniq | xargs du -sh
```

This failed with a: `xargs: unterminated quote` thanks to varied quote marks within the filenames.

So I ended up utilizing `find` with `-print0` and `xargs` with `-0`:

```
find -E . -type f -regex '.*[fF][oO][oO].*' -maxdepth 2 -print0 | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev | egrep -v '\.$' | uniq | xargs -0 du -sh
```

Yet I ended up an error: `du: Binary file (standard input) matches` thanks to `uniq` apparently munging the output from find's `-print0` formatting.

How would you suggest finding the parent folder size when searching for any file or folder under them that match?  I repeat, I simply want to find the top level folder names with their accompanying sizes (`du -sh`) and no subfolder path or file information so that I ultimately end up with just a nice neat list of main folders that have matching criteria.

Answer (score 2):

`rev` and `egrep` and `uniq` are all eating your zeros and seeing a single line. If you have GNU [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`uniq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) you can simplify this a lot:

```
find ...tests... -printf '%h\0' | uniq -z | xargs -0 du -sh
```

GNU `find`'s `-printf` option takes a format describing the output for each file. `%h` is the format for the path up to but not including the filename, and then `\0` makes it zero-terminated. `uniq -z` tells it to use zeros for terminating each record - otherwise it'll only see a single line, and essentially act like `cat`. `xargs` can then continue as you had it.

It's conceivable that [`sort -z -u`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) would be better than `uniq` to account for names out of order, although your maximum depth requirements mean that only `.` will appear more than once with anything in between. `-mindepth 2` would avoid that as well.

If none of your filenames have zeros in them

Answer (score 1):

The main complication in your example commands is getting the directory name.
You can get this much easier, directly, with the `-printf` option of `find`. It has a format for writing out the directory only: `%h`. Using that should allow to simplify your command a lot.

To write out the directories only, use:

```
find ... -type f ... -printf '%h\n'
```

You can use that for `\0`-terminated lines too:

```
find ... -type f ... -printf '%h\0'
```

The second command in the question has an extra problem: It uses a pipe of commands that work on lines, but the input is not lines - there are no newlines, as you use `\0` for line termination. To put it another way: the whole output is on one line.